# Очистка таблицы БД Room

Tags: android, kotlin

Всем привет. Появилась задача очистить таблицу БД Room (Android).
Пробовал создать в классе DAO метод:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM auto")
fun nukeAuto()
```

Насколько я понимаю этот метод должен удалить всё в таблице "auto", но того не происходит.
Действие я произвожу во вьюМодели (используя viewModelScope) :

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   appDatabase?.myCarDao()?.nukeAuto()
}
```

Но таблица не очищается.
Примеры брал отсюда:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244508/room-persistance-library-delete-all

Comment: Запрос действительно должен всё удалить из указанной таблицы. Но могут присутствовать обстоятельства, которые этому помешают - например, наличие внешних ключей. То есть надо смотреть результат выполнения запроса - статус и сообщение об ошибке. PS. TRUNCATE быстрее...

Comment: возможно `appDatabase=null` ? код верный

Comment: нет, он не null, абсолютно точно, создается в Application.onCreate

Comment: в дебаге dao, почему то, null

Comment: не понимаю что происходит, как до такого довели и что с этим делать...

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_drop_table.asp попробую truncate